# Android browser doesn't play html5 video from AWS S3 when CloudFront distribution is turned off

Tags: android, amazon-s3, html5-video, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to play HTML5 videos from  Amazon S3 and I can't figure out why they play normally on Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but Android browser (Android 2.3) says "This video cannot be played".

In S3 I changed the permissions for every video file to Open/Download to Everyone and I used the provided link in the  tag.

When I enable CloudFront instance pointed to my bucket and put it's links to  tag, everithing woks just fine. But Amazon charges additionally for using Cloudfront.

I will be very thankfull if someone tells me how to avoid that and use only S3 storage.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the files are being served with the correct **Content-Type** header, it shoud be 'video/mp4' for h264 video, and 'video/webm' for Google's Webm codec.